# Seems like the global exception handler is rethrowing the **BadHttpRequestException: Unexpected end of request content** as unhandled exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, error-handling, asp.net-core-webapi

My ASP .NET Core WebAPI application is getting some unidentified requests resulting in the below error.

**Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException: Unexpected end of request content.**

This error is getting logged only at the kestrel (stdout_logfile) and not in the application's error log. Seems like the global exception handler is rethrowing the exception as unhandled exception.

As the request keeps coming, the application becomes slow and gets crashed, ended up in restarting the supervisor to bring up the application.

**Error log:**

```
^[[41m^[[30mfail^[[39m^[[22m^[[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException: Unexpected end of request content.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException.Throw(RequestRejectionReason reason)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Http1ContentLengthMessageBody.ReadAsyncInternal(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpRequestStream.ReadAsyncInternal(Memory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.FileBufferingReadStream.ReadAsync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.StreamHelperExtensions.DrainAsync(Stream stream, ArrayPool`1 bytePool, Nullable`1 limit, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.NewtonsoftJsonInputFormatter.ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext context, Encoding encoding)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.BodyModelBinder.BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ParameterBinder.BindModelAsync(ActionContext actionContext, IModelBinder modelBinder, IValueProvider valueProvider, ParameterDescriptor parameter, ModelMetadata metadata, Object value)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerBinderDelegateProvider.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<CreateBinderDelegate>g__Bind|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)
```

**Code**

*Exception Filtering code:*

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    ...

    services.AddControllers()
            .ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options =>
            {
                options.SuppressConsumesConstraintForFormFileParameters = true;
                options.SuppressInferBindingSourcesForParameters = true;
                options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;
                options.SuppressMapClientErrors = true;
                options.ClientErrorMapping[StatusCodes.Status404NotFound].Link =
                    "https://httpstatuses.com/404";

                options.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = context =>
                {
                    var result = new BadRequestObjectResult(context.ModelState);

                    // TODO: add `using System.Net.Mime;` to resolve MediaTypeNames
                    result.ContentTypes.Add(MediaTypeNames.Application.Json);
                    result.ContentTypes.Add(MediaTypeNames.Application.Xml);

                    return result;
                };
            });

        services.AddControllers(options =>
            options.Filters.Add(new HttpResponseExceptionFilter())
        );
        
    ...
    ...
}
```

Why is error not caught at the below global handler, or why is the error getting rethrown as unhandled exception. What am I doing wrong here?

*Exception handler code:*

```
public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
{
    if (context.Exception is HttpResponseException exception)
    {
        logger.Error(context.Exception);

        context.Result = new ObjectResult(exception.Value)
        {
            StatusCode = exception.Status,
        };

        context.ExceptionHandled = true;
    }

    else if (context.Exception is BadHttpRequestException badException)
    {
        logger.Error(context.Exception);

        context.Result = new ObjectResult(badException.Data.Values)
        {
            StatusCode = badException.StatusCode,
        };

        context.ExceptionHandled = true;
    }

    else if (context.Exception is Exception otherException)
    {
        logger.Error(context.Exception);

        context.Result = new ObjectResult(otherException.Data.Values)
        {
            StatusCode = otherException.HResult,
        };

        context.ExceptionHandled = true;
    }
}
```